# Is 'Close to' a phrasal verb?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

1. India is close to being a superpower.

Is 'close to' a verbal phrase?

Comment: _Close to_ is neither a phrasal verb nor a verbal phrase (which are not the same thing). _Close_ is a locational adjective which takes a _to_ prepositional phrase with object  nouns that denote locations (in this case, the location is metaphorical, on an imaginary scale of national power). _Close_ is the predicate adjective of the sentence, _is_ is the auxiliary verb. By the way, you may have been confused because of the spelling. There is a verb _close_, but it's pronounced /kloz/, while the adjective _close_ of _close to_ is pronounced /klos/, with an /s/, not a /z/.

Comment: @JohnLawler - Isn't "to being" claimed to be a "verbal phrase" or some such, not a "prepositional phrase"?

Comment: I agree with JL. "Close" is an adjective with the preposition phrase "to being a superpower" as its complement. The whole expression "close to being a superpower" is thus an adjective phrase functioning as predicative complement of "be".

Comment: @HotLicks _To being_ is not a phrase of any sort. It's not a constituent, just a string, like _one of_. _To_ goes with _being a superpower_, not just with _being_

Comment: @Lambie - You forget rule #1 of English grammar!

Comment: @HotLicks Never mind that.

Comment: However, we could say: India is closing rapidly on superpower status.

Answer (score 1):

The verb in your sentence is *is*—a linking verb. That makes *close* a subject complement and a predicate adjective.

*To* is a preposition. The object of that preposition is *being a superpower*—a gerund phrase that functions as noun.*

To test this, you can add an adverb and swap in a noun:

> *India is close to being a superpower.*
>
> *India is very close to China.*

<sub>*Warning: Grammar terms vary.</sub>